# How often can the words in a sentence be rearranged to form different but similarly likely setentence

Tags: english, reference-request, word-order, language-models

I have a conjecture that given a particular (multi)set of words without knowledge of ordering, then one ordering is normally much more likely than any others.

- Its not always true,

  - Show me flights from Paris to New York." is just as reasonable as "Show me flights from New York to Paris"; and just as likely to occur in real world use.
- On the other hand often one ordering is far more likely and reasonable than the others,

  - "The dog chased the cat." is much more often correct than "The cat chased the dog.", it is also preferable over "The cat the dog chased."
  - though all three are grammatical.
  - Indeed the sentence "The cat chased the dog." may in-fact be the correct sentence (My old neighbor had a cat like that), but how often does it occur? Maybe 1 time in 1000?
- so perhaps it is true for 90% (for example) of sentences.

Fundamentally the question comes down **to given a Bag of Words, how often can a good stochastic language model order them correctly** (back to the reference the bag came from.).

I'm looking for a reference based on corpus statistics. (My own results suggest it is true for the Brown corpus, though I'ld much rather cite an existing well-known work)

I'm primarily interested in English, though a contrastive notes [with more or less strict word-ordering languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/557/languages-with-stricter-and-less-strict-word-order) would be very interesting.

Comment: This seems related to http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9515/can-the-entropy-per-word-be-caculated-preciselyand-relation-among-information-t?rq=1 though that is a theoretical question i think. I haven't yet fully digested it.